# Hazelcast Instance failing on startup due to Serializer overwrite

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am running hazelcast 3.6.3 and when I run the following with no config:

```
Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
```

I get an exception as follows:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [class java.util.LinkedList] serializer cannot be overridden!
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.safeRegister(AbstractSerializationService.java:331)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.safeRegister(AbstractSerializationService.java:326)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DefaultSerializationServiceBuilder.registerSerializerHooks(DefaultSerializationServiceBuilder.java:294)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DefaultSerializationServiceBuilder.build(DefaultSerializationServiceBuilder.java:220)
at com.hazelcast.instance.DefaultNodeExtension.createSerializationService(DefaultNodeExtension.java:125)
at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.<init>(Node.java:174)
at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:125)
at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:160)
at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:143)
at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:111)
at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:87)
...
```

I have not registered any serializers and this same code works when I downgrade to 3.5.3.  Do I need to do anything to change the configuration?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have different Hazelcast versions in your classpath? Serializers are registered automatically by picking up registration files from the classpath, therefore it sounds like you would have Hazelcast 3.5.3 and the new version 3.6.3 inside your classpath which will end up in registering it twice.

Comment: I'm running inside a spring boot container and building using gradle.  When I change from version 3.5.3 to version 3.6.3 in the `build.gradle` file, run `gradlew clean build`, and run the container as a java process using `java -jar hazelcast-test.jar` I believe that I have removed any old versions of the Hazelcast jar.

Comment: Please extract and see that there is really no two versions inside this JAR file.

Comment: Ok, now I feel foolish.  There was a second version of Hazelcast that had been put in the hazelcast-test.jar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

noctarius was correct.  This was caused by two versions of the hazelcast.jar file within the Spring Boot packaged jar.